# Make A Div Appear And Then Stay On Refresh Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

i made a div that appears when we click the button and im trying to make it stay when i refresh the page but disapear when browser is closed.

```
<body>
    <p>Test</p>
    <div id="makeAppear" style="display: none;">
        <p>oui</p>
    </div>
    <button id="button">Block</button>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

```
let button = document.getElementById('button');
let testThatStaysOnRefresh = document.getElementById('makeAppear');

button.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
    testThatStaysOnRefresh.style.display ="block";
});
```

Comment: You need to store the visibility state of the button somehow: look into localStorage or sessionStorage.

Comment: Of course it does; unless you're doing something to persist that state, it will revert to its default state. You need to use something like `localStorage`.

Comment: I wonder how to distinguish between refresh and close+open on `localStorage`point of view...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can look into '[sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)'

> The sessionStorage property accesses a session Storage object for the current origin. sessionStorage is similar to localStorage; the difference is that while data in localStorage doesn't expire, data in sessionStorage is cleared when the page session ends.
>
> **A page session lasts as long as the browser is open, and survives over page reloads and restores.**

Update script.js to check the session store on load to get the appropriate behavior

```
let button = document.getElementById('button');
let testThatStaysOnRefresh = document.getElementById('makeAppear');

button.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
    sessionStorage.setItem('flagClicked',true); // used to store the state across refreshes, the key can be anything
    testThatStaysOnRefresh.style.display ="block";
});

//used to restore the state based on the session storage value, it gets executed when the page is refreshed and the style is set appropriately based on the value.
if(sessionStorage.getItem('flagClicked') {
    testThatStaysOnRefresh.style.display ="block";
}
```

Comment: happy to help :)

Comment: Can i also store functions in localstorage ?

Comment: They would be stored as strings, so not really. But then again, you can use eval to evaluate function strings, but that would be highly insecure and not recommended.